# Pass QuerySet to Celery Task in Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, celery, pickle

I want to move some long query to the async task in Celery and next retrieve that extra-info with AJAX. Now I get QuerySet like this:

```
brands = Brand.objects.filter(shops__shop_name__in=[shop])
```

Task:

```
@task()
def brand_count(querystr):
    querystr.annotate(amount_of_products=Count('products'))
```

I want to do like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31189228/8495108):

```
task_run = brand_count.delay(brands)
```

The question is: **How to pass a QuerySet to Celery task?** Now it throws an error that this couldn't be done. 
I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36262322/8495108) that `pickle` might be used here, but I can't get the right way to use it. Specially - what does `# Assuming 's' is the pickled string.` in `query = pickle.loads(s)` mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you discovered you can't pass a queryset to the task directly, because the task arguments must be serializable. Pickling is not a good ideal either as you don't actually need to serialize the entire queryset.

Instead you should pass a list of object IDs to the task, and then fetch the queryset from the task itself.

```
brand_ids = Brand.objects.filter(shops__shop_name__in=[shop]).values_list('id', flat=True)
task_run = brand_count.delay(list(brand_ids))
```

[`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) will give you a list of IDs for the brands.

Then, in your task, you recreate the queryset and do what you need with it:

```
@task()
def brand_count(brand_ids):
    queryset = Brand.objects.filter(id__in=brand_ids)
    queryset.annotate(amount_of_products=Count('products'))
```

Comment: Yes, I have also got an idea to pass just id-s to the task. But your realization is brilliant.